# EF Core MySql does not show enum values

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, enums, ef-core-2.2

In my project I am using asp.net core 2.2 and mysql for db. Before when I selected enum values (before used postgre) it showed exact values for me, but now it shows integers instead of values.

My startup connection:

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => 
     x.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibvirtConnection"))
                .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning)));
```

My select stament:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult GetVMs()
    {
        var model =
            from vm in _context.VirtualMachines
            join project in _context.Projects on vm.ProjectId equals project.Id
            join hypervisor in _context.Hypervisors on vm.HypervisorId equals 
             hypervisor.HypervisorId
            join managment in _context.Managements on vm.ManagementId equals managment.Id
            select new
            {
                Id = vm.Id,
                Name = vm.Name,
                IpAddress = vm.IpAddress,
                DiskSize = vm.DiskSize,
                Cpu = vm.CPU,
                Ram = vm.Ram,
                ImageUrl = vm.ImageUrl,
                Role = vm.Role.ToString(),
                Status = vm.Status.ToString(),
                Project = project.Name,
                Hypervisor = hypervisor.Name,
                Gateway = managment.Gateway,
                Netmask = managment.Netmask
            };
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

I got result back:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "kubernetesvm",
    "ipAddress": "185.22.98.7",
    "diskSize": 500,
    "cpu": 24,
    "ram": 500,
    "imageUrl": "https://www.google.com",
    "role": "1",
    "status": "0",
    "project": "avengers",
    "hypervisor": "kubernetes",
    "gateway": "vh10",
    "netmask": 24
}
```

It should be actual values for role and status.

Comment: Did you inspect your mySql table to see if columns are varchar or int

Comment: @Jawad it is integer, also migrations used integer, with postgre it worked perfect before

Comment: Are you sure that the `0` is in your enum?

Comment: What datatype is `vm.Role`

Comment: @MindSwipe it is enum

Comment: @Hadi yes I am sure, again it worked fine with postgre before

Comment: @Hadi in C# enums are a glorified wrapper around an int value ([at least for now](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/discriminated-unions.md)) which starts counting at 0

Comment: @MindSwipe but you can set a starting value to the enum.

Comment: Try to specify the format on the `ToString` of the enum manually by giving `"G"` as the parameter

Comment: @MindSwipe many thanks. It works like charm now!!

Comment: Great to have been able to help, if you don't mind accepting my answer so we can lower the (comparatively) high unanswered question percentage on this site togheter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ToString()` on the Enum uses the default format specifier `"D"`, which prints the number behind the Enum value, but when specifying the format manually to be `"G"` the `ToString("G")` method returns the name as it is written in source, so that should fix your problem, replace `.ToString()` with `.ToString("G")`

So:

```cs
Role = vm.Role.ToString("G"),
Status = vm.Status.ToString("G")
```